# Pandas - groupby and transform to group number

Tags: python, pandas

Assuming I have this df:

```
    group1  group2
0    0       0
1    1       0
2    0       1
3    0       1
4    0       0
```

What I need is to simply groupby "group1" and "group2" columns  -and create a new column ("new_group") with simply the ordinal number of the groupby.
So the result should be:

```
    group1  group2   new_group
0    0       0         0
1    1       0         1
2    0       1         2
3    0       1         2
4    0       0         0
```

I tried using `transform` - but I didn't find the exact syntax I should use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with [ngroup](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.ngroup.html):

```py
df['new_group'] = df.groupby(['group1', 'group2']).ngroup()
```