# Setting a new ID column starting from 1 to n according to groups

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Suppose I have a dataframe that looks like

```
STATUS;Date;oldID
Status1ab;16.02.2023 09:46:32;9780094632160223
Status2ab;13.04.2023 23:59:59;9780094632160223
Status1ab;16.02.2023 09:46:32;9781094632160223
Statusc;13.04.2023 23:59:59;9781094632160223
Statusd;28.02.2023 19:37:01;3915193701280223
Statuse;28.04.2023 20:37:01;3915193701280223
Statusf;02.05.2023 20:39:02;3915193701280224
```

Now I would like to create a new ID column that starts from 1 and goes up to n, however according to the "ID groups" in the oldID column. That means in the example it should be like this:

```
STATUS;Date;oldID;newID
Status1ab;16.02.2023 09:46:32;9780094632160223;1
Status2ab;13.04.2023 23:59:59;9780094632160223;1
Status1ab;16.02.2023 09:46:32;9781094632160223;2
Statusc;13.04.2023 23:59:59;9781094632160223;3
Statusd;28.02.2023 19:37:01;3915193701280223;4
Statuse;28.04.2023 20:37:01;3915193701280223;4
Statusf;02.05.2023 20:39:02;3915193701280224;5
```

(This is just an example. My file is quite large, I cannot map it manually with assigning the values manually with typing every ID.)

I thought there should be a solution for this. I tried to figure it out with groupby and answers from other questions, but failed. I then tried to export just the oldID column to a new dataframe, groupby it there by oldID and assign a new column with values starting from 1 and merging it back. But this is quite an inefficient workaround I think.

This [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72030019/pandas-groupby-and-transform-to-group-number) comes close, but I would like to have it starting at 1 for the first entry "9780094632160223" like in my example. So when I use that solution it seems to build up new ids correctly, but it starts with high values for the first entry, not at 1.

Comment: Can you try `df['newID'] = df.groupby('oldID', sort=False).ngroup().add(1)` ?

Comment: Or `df['newID'] = pd.factorize(df['oldID'])[0] + 1`

Comment: I checked the first one and it works, you can post it as an answer.

Comment: It is duplicate, so cannot do it.